# Is it possible to use the Docusign APIs with IronPython

Tags: docusignapi, ironpython

I am wondering if it is possible to use the Docusign APIs with IronPython. My script works fine with Python, but when I use IronPython, I get the following error: LookupError: unknown error handler name 'surrogatepass'. My guess is that it's not possible because IronPython is python 2 whereas the Docusign APIs are written for python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be right. Looking up this error I found this thread (https://bugs.python.org/issue8438) which suggests that you need to use Python 3. 
There was supposed to be an IronPython version that supports Python 3 (https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3) but appears they say not to use it as they migrated to a different approach. So, not sure that would work either. You can always try to make API calls directly without using an SDK, it's just more work unfortunately.